# error installing openssl for python (pip)

Tags: python, pip, openssl, cryptography, binance

i'm trying to install openssl using pip in order to use it with python.
i tried several versions and i get the same error!
i tried pip install cryptography and got the same error !
visual studion sdk builder is installed and worked for other packages.
please help, i attached the  log after running "pip install pyopenssl !

log with the end error:

```
building '_openssl' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\teich\PycharmProjects\first\venv\include -ID:\Users\teich\A
ppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -ID:\Users\teich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\
INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Wind
ows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win6
4\OpenSSL-win64" /Tcbuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.obj
  _openssl.c
  build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\_openssl.c(498): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslv.h': No such file or directory
```